# Statically calculate execution time and memory consumption of C program

Tags: c, profiling, valgrind, hard-real-time

I work on a language that compiles to C99 with no mallocs, no recursion, and no loops. All memory is pre-allocated, and all functions terminate (unless there's an exception like division by zero).

The entry point of my module is always the same: a function `void step(void)`.

Is there a tool that, under such circumstances, will calculate the max memory usage and max execution time of my code?

Comment: You already know the memory usage because the memory is preallocated (i.e.) doing `size ./myprogram` will give you that. It's [really!] hard to discern the execution time without representative code (and I can't imagine code with no loops/recursion [in place of loops]). So, without loops, I presume you don't have arrays. Some static analysis tool might produce something (e.g. O(n)), but the _actual_ execution time really depends on actually _executing_ the code with benchmarking as the exec time depends on CPU/model, system loading, memsize, membus speed, cache size/speed, etc.

Answer (score -1):

`valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes --pages-as-heap=yes`

The above should profile all of the memory use.

Alternatively, while your executable is running you can use `pmap -x PID` (or look at /proc/PID/maps).

For the execution time, I would just use `/usr/bin/time -p exe_name`

Comment: The question asks for static calculations and for the maximums. Running the program with Valgrind or `/usr/bin/time` is not static and covers only the cases exercised, not the maximums over all possible inputs.

Comment: It's tagged Valgrind and profiling which makes it ambiguous in my book.